# Reading from .csv file into vector of vector of strings with unknown # rows/columns

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, csv, vector

I'm reading in from an excel file into a vector of vector of strings. However, the first line of my example excel file has 12 columns and when I try to read in that line into a single string in a while loop with `while(getline(file,line,'\n'))`, it gets most of it but at the end of the string it finishes with "..."

I'm assuming this is because the string cannot hold any more information. One workaround I tried was to simply use `while (getline(file, line,','))` and save each element in each column in its respective index in its vector. This way actually works better for me because I'm going to have to do this anyways so I might as well start off with doing it. However...doing it this way is complicated because I have no way of knowing when the pointer has moved to the next line. Without knowing when it's at the end of the line, I can't possibly put each element in the correct index of the vector. How can I know when the pointer is at the end of the line or is there a different way to approach this problem?

This is in C++

```
vector<vector<string>> list;
int size; //number of columns
while(getline(file,line,','))
{
vector<string> test;
list.push_back(test);
list[i%size].push_back(line)
}
```

Comment: Post code and sample input. And `while (getline(file, line,','))` won't work.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I've added sample code. Not sure how you want me to add sample excel input. It's just like `Name | Phone | Address`. And why won't `while (getline(file,line,','))` work?

Comment: Well, it obviously won't work if your field separator is a `|`  and not a comma. But even if it is a comma, it won't work because a record does not end in a comma.

Comment: Oh I just used the | to represent the end of a cell in excel. It's not like that in the excel file. I do believe it separates them by commas though. When I open the excel file up in notepad, the entries are as follows: `"Name","Phone","Address"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try the std::stringstream to split the comma.
Here is a sample code for reading csv file to a 2D vector:

```
vector<vector<string>> list;    
ifstream file("myfile.csv");
while(file){
  string line;
  if(!getline(file,line)) break;

  istringstream ss(line);
  vector<string> words;

  while(ss){
    string s;
    if(!getline(ss, s, ',')) break;
    words.push_back(s);
  }
  list.push_back(words);
}
```

Testing:

```
for(size_t row = 0, maxrow = list.size(); row < maxrow; row++)
{
    for (size_t col = 0, maxcol = list[row].size(); col < maxcol; col++)
        cout << list[row][col] << ", ";
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: This works. One thing I noticed though is that when I copied the value of "line" from Visual Studio, it always ended in "..." when I pasted it somewhere. However, the actual value doesn't end in "...". This happened with my method as well as this method.